# Php smtp error on send mail

Tags: php, email, smtp

So, i am making a script to send an email that does not go to the spam folder, therefore i'm using smtp authentication, but the problem is i can't get it to work, i downloaded the pear files and set them up for the includes, but still not working and i am getting these errors, anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

Warning: include_once(Net/SMTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 365

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php71/lib/php') in /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 365

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Net_SMTP' not found in /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/php/Mail/smtp.php:366 Stack trace: #0 /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/php/Mail/smtp.php(271): Mail_smtp->getSMTPObject() #1 /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/php/Mail/smtp.php(258): Mail_smtp->send_or_fail('henriquemmceles...', Array, 'Hi,\n\nHow are yo...') #2 /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/php/register_front_php.php(145): Mail_smtp->send('henriquemmceles...', Array, 'Hi,\n\nHow are yo...') #3 /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/register_front.php(3): include('/home2/anfisool...') #4 {main} thrown in /home2/anfisool/public_html/maquinasdeoutrostempos.com/lab2/login/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 366

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIzd8.png), 
[Inside the Mail folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4J9l.png)

Also the content in the variables $from, $host, $username and $password are censored for obvious reasons in this case, but i am sure the credencials are correct.

```
require_once "Mail.php";

        $to = $_SESSION['email'];
         $subject = "Hi!";
         $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
         $from = "***************";

         $host = "***********";
         $username = "******************";
         $password = "******";

         $headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
         $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

         $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
         if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
           echo("" . $mail->getMessage() . "");  
          } else {   
            echo("Message successfully sent!");  
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you try PHPMailer instead of PEAR https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Agreed with the above, you didn't set up the PEAR classes properly - better go with PHPMailer or swiftmailer, more modern alternatives.